# Parsing HTML without adding and removing tags

Tags: html, python-2.7, parsing, beautifulsoup

In Beautifulsoup when you parse HTML it attempts to *finish* the HTML for you, for example:

```
HTML = """<!doctype html>
<html>
<body>
<img src='test'/>
<p
"""
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
print BeautifulSoup(HTML, "html.parser")
```

Output of this will be:

```
<!DOCTYPE doctype html>

<html>
<body>
<img src="test"/>
    &lt;p
    </body></html>
```

Is there a way I can parser the HTML *as is* without editing any of the tags or the HTML data (tags, `<`, `>`, etc), or is there an alternative method to parsing HTML "as is"?

Comment: "it attempts to finish the HTML for you" — It is just following the rules for HTML parsing as defined in the HTML specification.

Answer (score 0):

No.

The point of parsing is to transform the HTML source code into a model of the document (so you can manipulate it programmatically).

The `<p` gets turned into a text node containing `<p`, and the `<html>` and `<body>` tags generate HTML and BODY *elements*.

Any manipulation is then done to the model.

Then, at some point, you turn the model back into HTML. This doesn't (and can't, at least not reasonably) take the original source code into consideration. It escapes special characters (like `<`) in text nodes, and it generates end tags for elements which can have end tags. The result is a normalised document.

Comment: so there is no alternative method?